# Counting the occurrence of one or more substrings in a string

Tags: string, algorithm, go

I know that for counting the occurrence of one substring I can use "strings.Count(, )". What if I want to count the number of occurrences of substring1 OR substring2? Is there a more elegant way than writing another new line with strings.count()?

Comment: If you search for "ab" and "bb" in "abb", how many occurrences are there? That is, do you want to count non-overlapping instances or overlapping instances?

Comment: @PaulHankin should be one occurence in that case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/):

https://play.golang.org/p/xMsHIYKtkQ

```
aORb := regexp.MustCompile("A|B")

matches := aORb.FindAllStringIndex("A B C B A", -1)
fmt.Println(len(matches))
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of regex! I read the documentation but couldn't find a case where the strings are variables. So I wonder what if the words are variable and I won't know how many there are, does Golang's regex supports that?

Comment: @IceBear: I don't understand what you mean. That doesn't have anything to do with regex, do you just want to know how to format a string?

Comment: I figured it out, I created an empty string and append the variable name and a "|" to the string to construct the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do substring matching is with the [suffixarray](https://golang.org/pkg/index/suffixarray/) package. Here is an example of matching multiple patterns:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "index/suffixarray"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile("an")
    index := suffixarray.New([]byte("banana"))
    results := index.FindAllIndex(r, -1)
    fmt.Println(len(results))
}
```

You can also match a single substring with the [Lookup](https://golang.org/pkg/index/suffixarray/#Index.Lookup) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of matches in a large string, without allocating space for all the indices just to get the length and then throwing them away, you can use [`Regexp.FindStringIndex`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindStringIndex) in a loop to match against successive substrings:

```golang
func countMatches(s string, re *regexp.Regexp) int {
    total := 0
    for start := 0; start < len(s); {
        remaining := s[start:] // slicing the string is cheap
        loc := re.FindStringIndex(remaining)
        if loc == nil {
            break
        }
        // loc[0] is the start index of the match,
        // loc[1] is the end index (exclusive)
        start += loc[1]
        total++
    }
    return total
}

func main() {
    s := "abracadabra"
    fmt.Println(countMatches(s, regexp.MustCompile(`a|b`)))
}
```

[runnable example at Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Dx4C7G4xJpp)